# How to wipe auto backup data

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-backup-service

I read [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/backup/autosyncapi.html#testing) article. As you can see it says that I need to execute the following command:

```
adb shell bmgr wipe <TRANSPORT> <PACKAGE>
```

NOTE that I'm using Windows OS.

To get the `Transport` value I executed the following command:

```
adb shell bmgr list transports
```

Which returned me the following list:

```
    android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport
  * com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService
```

I tried to wipe data using all of the following commands:

```
adb shell bmgr wipe android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport com.myapp
adb shell bmgr wipe * com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService com.myapp
adb shell bmgr wipe com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService com.myapp
adb shell bmgr wipe com.google.android.gmsandroid/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport com.myapp
adb shell bmgr wipe com.google.android.gms* com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService com.myapp
adb shell bmgr wipe com.google.android.gmscom.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService com.myapp
adb shell bmgr wipe com.google.android.gms.android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport com.myapp
adb shell bmgr wipe com.google.android.gms.* com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService com.myapp
adb shell bmgr wipe com.google.android.gms.com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService com.myapp
```

But none of them worked i.e. after installing the application there were still data from previous installation. So which command should I use to wipe auto backup data?

Answer (score 2):

I wondered in which form I had to enter the TRANSPORT too. Thanks for testing!
If you want to wipe the backup and can't to it because the it is unclear how to call the wipe properly you could try to disable and enable the auto backup.

```
adb shell bmgr enable false
adb shell bmgr enable true
```

Citing from https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bmgr.html last paragraph:

> Warning! When backup is disabled, the current backup transport will explicitly wipe the entire active data set from its backend storage. This is so that when a user says they do not want their data backed up, the Backup Manager respects that wish. No further data will be saved from the device, and no restore operations will be possible, unless the Backup Manager is re-enabled (either through Settings or through the above bmgr command).

Answer (score 2):

To list the transports:

```
adb shell bmgr list transports
```

To cancel a backup use the selected transport (the one with *) and the package id:

```
adb shell bmgr wipe  android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport  com.test.myapp
```

You should get a result:

```
Wiped backup data for com.test.myapp on android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport
```